# Apple rejects app using Nearby for microphone use

Tags: ios, google-nearby

We tried to submit an app to the play store and got rejected:

> The microphone consent request is generated by the use of either
>   AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
>   audio categories. If you do not intend to record audio with your app,
>   please choose the AVAudioSession session category that fits your app's
>   needs or modify your app to include audio-recording features.

We don't use the app other than whatever the Nearby library does. Has anyone else released an app to the play store and got past this roadblock?

Comment: `Google Nearby` has a large amount of dependencies even if you are never using them: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/f/b/9/NearbyMessages/1.1.0/NearbyMessages.podspec.json It links to: `CoreAudio, MediaPlayer, AudioToolbox, etc..` It depends on other Google pods which might link even more libraries.. Google adds so much crap to their pods that you may not actually need or use.. One example is `FireBase` which installs every pod Google has.. These reasons are why I stopped using Google pods.. Apple was able to trigger a popup for unneeded Microphone permissions in your app.

Comment: The Nearby library supports audio and BLE for discovery of nearby devices.  Even if your app doesn't use the audio feature, Apple will still flag it as using audio because of the API calls it makes.

Did Apple complain about the lack of NSMicrophoneUsageDescription in your Info.plist?  If so, add this entry with a token string.  It's unfortunate to have to do this, but it's necessary to get past the approval process.